# How can I add/remove elements based on total count of element value of another element value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am trying to add/remove elements from array based on total count of another value.

```
let data = [
    {
  "details": [
    {
      "Name": "DataSet1",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 20
    },
    {
      "Name": "DataSet2",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 30
    },
    {
      "Name": "DataSet3",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 25
    }
  ],
  "charge": 45
}
];
```

Here, I am trying to get an array such that total value of Cost is near to charge. Here, Sum of Cost is 75 which is greater than 45, so I tried like below:

1. Calculate difference between charge and total cost, If it's greater than charge, then remove elements from array, such that new array total cost always less or near to charge. So, my new array should be:

```
let newdata = [
    {
  "details": [
    {
      "Name": "DataSet1",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 20
    },
    {
      "Name": "DataSet3",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 25
    }
  ],
  "charge": 50
}
];
```

Is there any better way to do this? Does Javascript have any built-in functionality that does this?

Comment: Better than what? And no, this sounds like a very specific scenario. You'll have to use loops to loop over the `details` array and determine what entry in the array should be removed. Could you show your attempt?

Comment: Better than using multiple loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "charge": 50,
  "details": [{
      "Name": "DataSet1",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 20
    },
    {
      "Name": "DataSet2",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 30
    }, {
      "Name": "DataSet3",
      "Severity": "4",
      "Cost": 25
    }
  ],
};
const getItemsAndDontGoAboveCharge =
  (charge, list, start = 0, currentCost = 0, result = []) => {
    if (start === list.length) return result
    const {
      Cost
    } = list[start]
    const nextTotal = currentCost + Cost
    if (nextTotal > charge) return result
    return getItemsAndDontGoAboveCharge(charge, list, start + 1, nextTotal, [...result, list[start]]);
  }

console.log(getItemsAndDontGoAboveCharge(data.charge, data.details))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! For my learning, Is there any other alternative way to get this using slice and reduce functions?

Comment: there is, but it's not great since filter/reduce traverse the WHOLE array, and there's no way to stop them. So you'll end up traversing items you don't need which obviously isn't good for performance